# Share authentication information among 2 .NET applications hosted on different servers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, security, asp.net-web-api

I want to share an authentication information among 2 .NET applications developed using ASP.NET WebForms 2.0 & ASP.NET MVC 4.0, hosted on different servers.

The user will log-in in ASP.NET WebForms application. His authentication will be perform in ASP.NET WebForms application. The user will see the list of products he/she has purchased. Out of his/her product list few products are from the other MVC 4.0 application. Once the user clicks the product link in WebForms 2.0 application, he/she will be presented with the product details and information in form of simple HTML pages which are stored and hosted in MVC 4.0 application. There is no means and no point of storing user information in MVC4.0 application as the end user is WebForms application user.

The problem is basically with the security of the product HTML contents from MVC 4.0 application. What if user copies and shares the link with other user? As there is no authentication happens at the MVC 4.0 application side and the MVC 4.0 application is treating the request as authenticated, the other user will get authenticated and will be presented with the contents which should not happen.

Kindly suggest me how can I address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need a SSO (Single sign on) solution. Check Microsoft Federation Services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx